# autocomplete xml/html in non-xml/html files

Tags: visual-studio-code

The problem is simple, but I cannot seem to find a good solution.
When using Visual Studio Code, it applies HTML or XML autocomplete in
C++ files.

In C++ files (e.g., `*.cpp` and `*.h`), when I type `<`, it automatically inserts a closing `>` as if working with an XML or HTML file.

This always happens when I go to change an `==` to a `<=` by selecting the first `=` char, or any other time I am replacing text with a `<` (it changes to `<=>=`, surrounding the selected text with `<>`)

One solution I think is to disable autocomplete for XML and HTML entirely, but I do work with these files as well, so I'd prefer some option to simply keep this method of autocomplete outside `*.cpp` and `*.h` files.

Visual Studio does not seem to do this, but some of my MCU environments run in Visual Studio Code instead of Visual Studio.

(Edit: Including Help: About)

> Version: 1.85.1 (user setup)
> Commit: 0ee08df0cf4527e40edc9aa28f4b5bd38bbff2b2
> Date: 2023-12-13T09:49:37.021Z
> Electron: 25.9.7
> ElectronBuildId: 25551756
> Chromium: 114.0.5735.289
> Node.js: 18.15.0
> V8: 11.4.183.29-electron.0
> OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.19045

Also, note that this still happens when all extensions are disabled.

As an example, when editing a CSV file and selecting 'ata, ota,     0x' from line 3

```
# Name,   Type, SubType, Offset,  Size, Flags
nvs,      data, nvs,     0x9000,  0x5000,
otadata,  data, ota,     0xe000,  0x2000,
app0,     app,  ota_0,   0x10000, 0x300000,
```

I get this result upon inserting a '<'

```
# Name,   Type, SubType, Offset,  Size, Flags
nvs,      data, nvs,     0x9000,  0x5000,
otadata,  d<ata, ota,     0x>e000,  0x2000,
app0,     app,  ota_0,   0x10000, 0x300000,
```

I've used a CSV file for example, but this same thing happens with all files I've tried so far except *.ini files.

Comment: Never seen that before. Is the language mode set to auto-detect? Your CPP files should show the text "C++" at the far-right of the status bar (bottom of window).

Comment: paddy: It is detected as c++. All features you would expect work normally (itellisence, etc) except when you type the '<' with text selected, it automatically inserts a closing '>'

Comment: starball: Updated the question. Interesting thing is the result is the same with extensions disabled.

Comment: does this happen no matter what the context of the content of the file is? does it happen at the beginning or end of the file? does it only happen when writing C++ expressions? please add a [mre].

Comment: It happens reguardless of context, and the effect is not even limited to C++ files. The only file type I've found where it doesn't do it so far is an ini file. (ive tried .cpp, .h, .txt, .html, .xml, .csv, .ini)

Comment: check your settings. especially the ones that have "auto closing" in their name.